# Retrieving data from server based on the data sent from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post, get

I want to send an id(string) from client to server side,  and based on that id, I want to retrieve  other information corresponding to that id from the server side. I'm using Node.js for back-end.

Also, I tried searching for this in Internet but couldn't find a solution. Hope it's not a dumb/already asked question.

Answer (score 1):

To send something from the front end to the back end and get a response is something you can do with Vanilla JS fetch api.

Here's an example:

```js
// Here, I'm making a request to an api with the following url:
const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'
const ID = 1

fetch(`${URL}/${ID}`)
  .then(res => res.json()) // parse the received information into json
  .then(json => console.log(json)) // print the json
```

The fetch api is making a request to the url and receives a corresponding response.  You can take a look at the MDN docs for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

---

Assuming you're using NodeJS + Express for the back end, you'd have to set up some kind of route.  Here's a very simple example of an express server.

```
// bring express into your server file
const express = require('express')

// if your front and back end run on different servers, you might need
// to worry about CORS, so you can also bring that in.
const cors = require('cors')

// initialize your application
const app = express()

// take care of cors problem by adding middleware
app.use(cors())

// let's say you have some user data in an array:
const users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "John"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Bill"
    }
]

// create your routes.  I'll just make one as an example.
// This route expects to receive a parameter as an id.  The URL
// would look like this: http://yourwebsite.com/123, where 123 is
// the id.
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    // get the id from the req.params object
    const { id } = req.params

    // do whatever you want with id. maybe fetch data from database
    // by id.  Here, we can just take data from users array.
    // We have to turn id into a Number, since params are strings 
    // by default.
    const foundUser = users.find(user => user.id === Number(id))

    // then we can return the user
    res.send(foundUser)
})

// finally, make sure your app is listening for incoming requests 
// on some port.  I'll just use port 3000 and make the server 
// console log a message if there are no errors.
app.listen(3000, console.log('Server listening on port 3000'))
```

---

If you're talking about how to make a request to another server from a server, you can use an npm package like axios or node-fetch.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

// then you can make a fetch request the same way it was done on the 
// front end

fetch('https://github.com/')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));
```

That being said, I would highly recommend you go to youtube or look at the official NodeJS/Express documentation, so you can really learn about what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Can you also add how do we handle such encoded requests in the back end?

Comment: Just added back end.

Comment: Thanks!  I will definitely do more research before asking such questions.